# '/usr/local/bin/curl' and '/usr/local/bin/ssh' commands are killed when executed in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew, monterey

I recently updated my M1 MacBook Air to macOS Monterey (I'm not sure if this is related to the problem though), and now my curl and ssh commands in /usr/local/bin don't function at all.

- Both commands immediately exit with `zsh: killed     *cmd*`
- In a bash shell the output is `Killed: 9`
- Both of these binaries in /usr/bin work fine. Since /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin in $PATH, the faulty one is executed first when I type the command by itself.
- No other commands in /usr/local/bin have this problem.
- These two commands are two of the three commands in the permission group admin in /usr/local/bin. The other is the code command for Visual Studio Code and it works fine.

From [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833310/what-is-killed9-and-how-to-fix-in-macos-terminal) it seems this can happen if a program uses too much memory and the system kills it, but since the command does nothing I don't think that's the case.

I also have Homebrew installed, I'm not sure if it is causing the problem:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.3.8
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 3f0b412951996a675b8a48037e9a978f0ccd8363
Last commit: 7 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: ce6e56a7aea61debc6ccbe4af77dd4e7d634a6dc
Core tap last commit: 20 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 13.0.0 build 1300
Git: 2.31.1 => /opt/homebrew/bin/git
Curl: 7.77.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.1-arm64
CLT: 13.2.0.0.1.1638488800
Xcode: 13.2.1
Rosetta 2: false
```

I have the curl package installed through Homebrew, but it is keg-only so it isn't symlinked and doesn't get used. I don't have the OpenSSH package installed through Homebrew.

I would appreciate any guidance on what the problem is or how to get more information than 'killed'.

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/bin/{ssh,curl}` return? How did you install them (on the previous system)?

Comment: How did they get into /usr/local - Homebrew runs from /opt/homebrew on M1 machine

Comment: I don't remember explicitly installing either of them into the folder. Are they not supposed to be in there normally (and Homebrew or some other user error put them there)?

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, I ran into the same problem after replacing an ancient 2012 Mac Pro server with an Apple Studio. It appears that macOS Monterey has new security "features" that make it impossible to install and execute programs in */usr/local/bin*. I simply moved them to */opt/bin* after creating that directory (and adding it to my `PATH`):

```
sudo mkdir /opt/bin
sudo chown krader /opt/bin
```

Comment: Can you add some details regarding that security feature, and how it explains that only some binaries in /usr/local/bin didn't work for the OP?